# How to play audio and video with same trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I want to use one play pause button for both tab. If you check the code, I have tried to play video and audio with same play pause button. But I can play only the audio with it, not the video.

If it is possible then how?

I have tried to do with update the id, when we switch between tab. but problem is it's not updating the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#audio_play").on("click", function () {
                $("#audio").get(0).play();
            })
            $("#audio_pause").on("click", function () {
                $("#audio").get(0).pause();
            })
            $('.menu ul li:nth(1)').on("click", function () {

                $("#audio_play").attr('id', 'video_play');
                $("#audio_pause").attr('id', 'video_pause');

            })
            $("#video_play").on("click", function () {
                $("#video").get(0).play();
            })
            $("#video_pause").on("click", function () {
                $("#video").get(0).pause();
            })
        })
```

```css
.con{
 text-align:center;
 width:156px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.2/alpine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full h-screen inset-x-0 mx-auto">
        <!--actual component start-->
        <div class="menu" x-data="setup()">
            <ul class="flex justify-center items-center my-4">
                <template x-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
                    <li class="cursor-pointer py-2 px-4 text-gray-500 border-b-8"
                        :class="activeTab===index ? 'text-green-500 border-green-500' : ''" @click="activeTab = index"
                        x-text="tab"></li>
                </template>
            </ul>

            <div class="w-full bg-white p-16 text-center mx-auto border">
                <div x-show="activeTab===0">
                <h1>Audio Player</h1>
                    <audio id="audio"
                        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/foxyplays989/video/upload/v1558369838/LetsGo.mp3"></audio>
                </div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===1">
                <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls src="move.mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
                </div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===2">Content 3</div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===3">Content 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--actual component end-->
    </div>
        <div class="flex con">
            <button class="inline-block px-6 py-2 text-xs font-medium leading-6 text-center text-white uppercase transition bg-blue-700 rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none" id="audio_play">play</button>
            <button class="inline-block px-6 py-2 text-xs font-medium leading-6 text-center text-white uppercase transition bg-red-500 rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none" id="audio_pause">Pause</button>
        </div>
    <script>
        function setup() {
            return {
                activeTab: 0,
                tabs: [
                    "Tab No.1",
                    "Tab No.2",
                ]
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Any one here to help me

Comment: The video won't play because the file is not found. Could you update your code with an actual video?

Comment: no need video try with simple console log. @José A. Zapata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently trying to use the `.play()` function on an `iframe` which simply is not possible as the error states `.play is not a function`.

What you want instead is using a html [`video` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) which provides this function.

There are even more issus with your code, see this list:

- Binding to a button is only happening on your `$(document).ready()` function. Once bound the action does not change, so it does not matter if you change the id of the element. A solution for that would be to re-bind the click event, with something like this:

  ```
  $("#video_play").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
    $("#video").get(0).play();
  })
  ```
- as stated above your binding needs to happen on tab change, so you should do something like this to re-bind your buttons every tab click:

  ```
  function setupButtons(){

    $("#video_play").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
        $("#video").get(0).play();
    })
    $("#video_pause").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
        $("#video").get(0).pause();
    })
    $("#audio_play").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
        $("#audio").get(0).play();
    })
    $("#audio_pause").unbind("click").on("click", function () {
        $("#audio").get(0).pause();
    })
    }



  $(document).ready(function () {

        setupButtons();

    $('.menu ul li:nth(1)').on("click", function () {

        setupButtons();
    })
  })
  ```
- the last issue is that your tab click only checks for a single switch from audio to video. i guess you want it to happen every click to have the right events bound on the right tab. so you would need to re-bind every tab click.
  so you could change the selector to `'.menu ul li'` and add some logic to your click handler to switch the buttons:

  ```
    $('.menu ul li').on("click", function () {

    if ($("#video_play").length){
            $("#video_play").attr('id', 'audio_play');
            $("#video_pause").attr('id', 'audio_pause');
        } else if ($("#audio_play").length){
            $("#audio_play").attr('id', 'video_play');
            $("#audio_pause").attr('id', 'video_pause');
        }

        setupButtons();
    })
  ```

Comment: I have modified code according to you info it's not working. it's playing only audio file not the video file. @Flo

Comment: Please update the code in your question, my guess is that you are still trying to play a vimeo video. this might be not possible at all, because they may block it. try using a url ending with `.mp4` instead.
but first please update your code above.

Comment: i updated my post to answer all your issues

Answer (score 1):

Changing the ID of the buttons does nothing, because it's the same element with the same click event attached to it. You need to change the behaviour of the button when you switch tabs. Unbind the click, then re-bind it again with the new behaviour. Check the updated code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#audio_play").on("click", function () {
                $("#audio").get(0).play();
            })
            $("#audio_pause").on("click", function () {
                $("#audio").get(0).pause();
            })
            $('.menu ul li:nth(0)').on("click", function () {

                $("#audio_play").unbind("click");
                $("#audio_pause").unbind("click");
                $("#audio_play").on("click", function () {
                    $("#audio").get(0).play();
                })
                $("#audio_pause").on("click", function () {
                    $("#audio").get(0).pause();
                })
            })
            $('.menu ul li:nth(1)').on("click", function () {

                $("#audio_play").unbind("click");
                $("#audio_pause").unbind("click");
                $("#audio_play").on("click", function () {
                    $("#video").get(0).play();
                })
                $("#audio_pause").on("click", function () {
                    $("#video").get(0).pause();
                })
            })

        })
```

```css
.con{
 text-align:center;
 width:156px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.2/alpine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full h-screen inset-x-0 mx-auto">
        <!--actual component start-->
        <div class="menu" x-data="setup()">
            <ul class="flex justify-center items-center my-4">
                <template x-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
                    <li class="cursor-pointer py-2 px-4 text-gray-500 border-b-8"
                        :class="activeTab===index ? 'text-green-500 border-green-500' : ''" @click="activeTab = index"
                        x-text="tab"></li>
                </template>
            </ul>

            <div class="w-full bg-white p-16 text-center mx-auto border">
                <div x-show="activeTab===0">
                <h1>Audio Player</h1>
                    <audio id="audio"
                        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/foxyplays989/video/upload/v1558369838/LetsGo.mp3"></audio>
                </div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===1">
                <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls src="video.mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
                </div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===2">Content 3</div>
                <div x-show="activeTab===3">Content 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--actual component end-->
    </div>
        <div class="flex con">
            <button class="inline-block px-6 py-2 text-xs font-medium leading-6 text-center text-white uppercase transition bg-blue-700 rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none" id="audio_play">play</button>
            <button class="inline-block px-6 py-2 text-xs font-medium leading-6 text-center text-white uppercase transition bg-red-500 rounded shadow ripple hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none" id="audio_pause">Pause</button>
        </div>
    <script>
        function setup() {
            return {
                activeTab: 0,
                tabs: [
                    "Tab No.1",
                    "Tab No.2",
                ]
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: yes you are right but i have slove this issue with  jquery delegate function  `$('body').on('click', '#addButton', function() {
   // code here
});`

Answer (score 0):

To use the code like `$("#video").get(0).play();` the element `"#video"` should be `<video>` HTML tag. You've inserted iframe which means that you load not a video which you available to control, but the page of other website which have included video.

You cannot modify content of iframe in your JavaScript, so you have to download some video and insert it as `<video>` HTML element (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).

Comment: I have modified code according to you  info it's not working. it's playing only audio file not the video file. @dragomirik

Comment: You updated with  `src="move.mp4"` which means that the file with name `move.mp4` should be at the same folder with the HTML code (try to insert the following link: `https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4`)